# Iptables issues with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I am having an issue appending new rules to iptables in ubuntu Here is what I believe is the relevant info.

Rule appending:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1022 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "SSH"
```

Error:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Version:

```
iptables v1.4.4
```

uname -r

```
2.6.18-028stab094.3
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Anyone have this issue before?

Comment: Maybe you need to put the -j option at the end ? iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1022 -m comment --comment "SSH" -j ACCEPT -> I confirm, it works

Comment: I tried that as well and it is still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you dont have the module **comment** compiled in your kernel, or loaded.

I copy & paste your line and it executes ok in my computer, debian wheezy, so is not a type error.

Comment: Really i only googled it. ;-)

Comment: Yea, I didn't even think that was a possibility.  I never ran into a system that didn't have it enabled.  I was making it more complicated than it needed to be.